# R create group variable based on row order and condition

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have a dataframe containing multiple groups that are not explicitly stated. Instead, new group always start when `type == 1`, and is the same for following rows, containing `type == 2`. The number of rows per group can vary.

How can I explicitly create new variable based on order of another column? The groups, of course, should be exclusive.

My data:

```
df <- data.frame(type = c(1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1),
                 stand = 1:10)
```

Expected output with new group `myGroup`:

```
   type stand myGroup
1     1     1       a
2     2     2       a
3     2     3       a
4     1     4       b
5     2     5       b
6     1     6       c
7     2     7       c
8     2     8       c
9     2     9       c
10    1    10       d
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option could be:

```
with(df, letters[cumsum(type == 1)])

[1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "c" "d"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `rep()` + `diff()`, but not as simple as the approach by [@tmfmnk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59835830/12158757)

```
idx <- which(df$type==1)
v <- diff(which(df$type==1))
df$myGroup <- rep(letters[seq(idx)],c(v <- diff(which(df$type==1)),nrow(df)-sum(v)))
```

such that

```
> df
   type stand myGroup
1     1     1       a
2     2     2       a
3     2     3       a
4     1     4       b
5     2     5       b
6     1     6       c
7     2     7       c
8     2     8       c
9     2     9       c
10    1    10       d
```